# How to show this function is locally integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Suppose $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ satisfies: $(1+|x|^2)^{s/2}f\in L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ for some $s>0$. How to show $(1+|x|^2)^sf$ is locally integrable?(integrable on any compact set.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove: If $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $f$ is locally integrable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416097/prove-if-f-in-lp-mathbbrn-then-f-is-locally-integrable)

Comment: You do not need your 2 hypothesis: anyone of the 2 is sufficient, + the fact that any function in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is locally integrable (see duplicate above), hence so is its product by any locally bounded measurable function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set. Then:
$$\int_{K} (1+|x|^2)^s |f(x)| \ dx \leq \left(\int_{K} (1+|x|^2)^s \ dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left(\int_{K} (1+|x|^2)^s |f(x)|^2 \ dx \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

by the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. I was able to do this by recognizing that:
$$(1+|x|^2)^s = (1+|x|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}} (1+|x|^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}$$

Since compact sets have finite measure, it follows that the first integral on the right-hand side above is finite. The finiteness of the second integral on the right-hand side follows from the hypothesis you gave.